# Получаю ошибку в связи с hash code в моём бине

Tags: java, java-ee, валидация, hashcode

Не могу понять причину данной ошибки.. Написано `Caused by NullPointerException`, в строке с hash кодом. Что тут в принципе приводит к ошибке?

Я инициализирую nickName, password, email: При создании User остальное будет Null, может проблема появляется при генерации hash кода значению null? почему?

```
    public static void main(String [] strings){

    ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();

    Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> constraints = validator.validate(new User("Stas","StasPassword","Stas.Stanis88@gmail.com"));

    for (ConstraintViolation<User> constraint:constraints) {

        System.out.println(constraint.getMessage());

    }

public class User {

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

private void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

private void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

private void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

private void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getCustomerType() {
    return customerType;
}

private void setCustomerType(String customerType) {
    this.customerType = customerType;
}

public String getNickName() {
    return nickName;
}

private void setNickName(String nickName) {
    this.nickName = nickName;
}

public User(){}

public User(String nickName,String password, String email){

    setEmail(email);
    setNickName(nickName);
    setPassword(password);
}

public User(String firstName, String lastName, String nickName ,String email, String password,  String customerType) {

    setCustomerType(customerType);
    setEmail(email);
    setFirstName(firstName);
    setLastName(lastName);
    setNickName(nickName);
    setPassword(password);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" +
            "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
            ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
            ", password='" + password + '\'' +
            ", email='" + email + '\'' +
            ", customerType='" + customerType + '\'' +
            ", nickName='" + nickName + '\'' +
            '}';
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    User user = (User) o;

    if (!getFirstName().equals(user.getFirstName())) return false;
    if (!getLastName().equals(user.getLastName())) return false;
    if (!getPassword().equals(user.getPassword())) return false;
    if (!getEmail().equals(user.getEmail())) return false;
    if (!getCustomerType().equals(user.getCustomerType())) return false;
    return getNickName().equals(user.getNickName());

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
107:    int result = getFirstName().hashCode(); // Проблемма возникает здесь! 
    result = 31 * result + getLastName().hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + getPassword().hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + getEmail().hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + getCustomerType().hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + getNickName().hashCode();
    return result;
}

@NotEmpty(message = "This field can't be empty")
@NotBlank(message = "This field can't be empty")
@Length(min = 0,max = 20,message = "The length of this field can be only 0-20")
private String firstName;

@NotEmpty(message = "This field can't be empty")
@NotBlank(message = "This field can't be empty")
@Length(min = 0,max = 20,message = "The length of this field can be only 0-20")
private String lastName;

@NotEmpty(message = "This field can't be empty")
@NotBlank(message = "This field can't be empty")
@Length(min = 8,max = 16,message = "Wrong password length: length of this field can be only 8-16")
private String password;

@NotEmpty(message = "This field can't be empty")
@NotBlank(message = "This field can't be empty")
@Email(message = "Wrong format for email field!" , regexp = "[A-Za-z.0-9]+@[A-Za-z.]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}")
private String email;

@NotEmpty(message = "This field can't be empty")
@NotBlank(message = "This field can't be empty")
private String customerType;

@NotEmpty(message = "This field can't be empty")
@NotBlank(message = "This field can't be empty")
@Length(min = 4,max = 10,message = "Wrong nickName: The length of this field can be only between 4-10")
private String nickName;

 }
```

---

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000041: ***Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception.***
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isReachable(ValidatorImpl.java:1405)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:1381)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:542)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:487)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:451)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:403)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:206)
    at UserValidationTest.main(UserValidationTest.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
***Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at coupon.beans.User.hashCode(User.java:107)***
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation$TraversableHolder.buildHashCode(CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation$TraversableHolder.<init>(CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation$TraversableHolder.<init>(CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.isReachable(CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isReachable(ValidatorImpl.java:1396)
    ... 12 more
```

---

```
public class User {

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

private void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

private void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

private void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

private void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getCustomerType() {
    return customerType;
}

private void setCustomerType(String customerType) {
    this.customerType = customerType;
}

public String getNickName() {
    return nickName;
}

private void setNickName(String nickName) {
    this.nickName = nickName;
}

    public User(){}

    public User(String nickName,String password, String email){

    setEmail(email);
    setNickName(nickName);
    setPassword(password);
}

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String nickName  ,String email, String password,  String customerType) {

    setCustomerType(customerType);
    setEmail(email);
    setFirstName(firstName);
    setLastName(lastName);
    setNickName(nickName);
    setPassword(password);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" +
            "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
            ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
            ", password='" + password + '\'' +
            ", email='" + email + '\'' +
            ", customerType='" + customerType + '\'' +
            ", nickName='" + nickName + '\'' +
            '}';
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    User user = (User) o;

    if (!getFirstName().equals(user.getFirstName())) return false;
    if (!getLastName().equals(user.getLastName())) return false;
    if (!getPassword().equals(user.getPassword())) return false;
    if (!getEmail().equals(user.getEmail())) return false;
    if (!getCustomerType().equals(user.getCustomerType())) return false;
    return getNickName().equals(user.getNickName());

}


           // Новый hash code метод! 
@Override
public int hashCode() {

    int result = getFirstName() == null ? 0:getFirstName().hashCode();

    result = 31 * result + getLastName() == null ? getLastName().hashCode():0;
    result = 31 * result + getPassword().hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + getEmail().hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + getCustomerType() == null ? getCustomerType().hashCode():0;
    result = 31 * result + getNickName().hashCode();
    return result;
}

@NotEmpty(message = "This field can't be empty")
@NotBlank(message = "This field can't be empty")
@Length(min = 0,max = 20,message = "The length of this field can be only 0-20")
private String firstName;

@NotEmpty(message = "This field can't be empty")
@NotBlank(message = "This field can't be empty")
@Length(min = 0,max = 20,message = "The length of this field can be only 0-20")
private String lastName;

@NotEmpty(message = "This field can't be empty")
@NotBlank(message = "This field can't be empty")
@Length(min = 8,max = 16,message = "Wrong password length: length of this field can be only 8-16")
private String password;

@NotEmpty(message = "This field can't be empty")
@NotBlank(message = "This field can't be empty")
@Email(message = "Wrong format for email field!" , regexp = "[A-Za-z.0-9]+@[A-Za-z.]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}")
private String email;

@NotEmpty(message = "This field can't be empty")
@NotBlank(message = "This field can't be empty")
private String customerType;

@NotEmpty(message = "This field can't be empty")
@NotBlank(message = "This field can't be empty")
@Length(min = 4,max = 10,message = "Wrong nickName: The length of this field can be only between 4-10")
private String nickName;

   }

    public static void main(String [] strings){

    ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();

    User user = new User("Stas","StasPassword","Stas.Stanis88@gmail.com");

    System.out.println(user);

    Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> constraints = validator.validate(user);

    for (ConstraintViolation<User> constraint:constraints) {

        System.out.println(constraint.getMessage());

    }
```

Вывод в консоль после проверки валидации :

Это после печати инициализированного обьекта.

```
User{firstName='null', lastName='null', password='StasPassword', email='Stas.Stanis88@gmail.com', customerType='null', nickName='Stas'}
```

Это при валидации этого обьекта:

```
This field can't be empty
This field can't be empty
This field can't be empty
This field can't be empty
This field can't be empty
This field can't be empty
```

`Null Pointer Exception` исчез, но валидатор относится к полям обьекта как к null, почему ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию значения полей ссылочных типов - `null`. При попытке вызвать у них метод `hashCode()` генерируется исключение `NullPointerException`, т.к. невозможно вызвать метод у объекта, который не существует. Для предотвращения данной ситуации проверяйте значение на `null` прежде, чем вызывать у него какие-либо методы.

В вашем случае можно написать так:

```
int result = getFirstName() == null ? 0 : getFirstName().hashCode();
```

Для остальных полей аналогично.

Comment: Добавил еше вопрос, буду рад если взгляните.